# How to efficiently swap 2 Tbytes variable?

Tags: delphi

I have 2 Tbytes var:

```
A: Tbytes;
B: Tbytes;
```

Now i want to swap then like this

```
tmp := A;
A := B;
B := tmp;
```

But I not sure if this is the most efficient way, especially with the copy-on-write (if it's the same as with String)

maybe something like this :

```
      Tmp := Pointer(a);
      pointer(a) := pointer(b);
      pointer(b) := Tmp ;
```

Comment: There is no copy on write. You could speed this up with pointer casts to suppress reference counting. However, I bet you have done no profiling. Have you?

Comment: how to do profiling ?

Comment: Why do you think you have a performance problem if you have lot measured performance?

Comment: i use TstopWatch but i was thinking by profiling you mean a special tool that i was not aware under delphi :)

Comment: What does your profiling tell you?

Comment: pointer is the most efficient :) but i ask also to know also about the theory :)

Comment: The theory is that you should only optimise code that is a bottleneck. Is this code a bottleneck?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : i fully disagree, it's better to have some idea of what must be done in the right way, than doing in the wrong way and later pass hours, days or months to find where the problem is. Changing just one instruction mean redebugging everything, and debuging is a very important part of programming and it's very time costly

Comment: Your opinion is very much the minority. The accepted doctrine of the professional programmer is "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Comment: That said, I agree that you should understand what the code is doing. Learning that dynamic arrays don't have copy of write, and that copy on write would not actually impact the code, is surely useful to you. Armed with all this knowledge you will be happy to swap using the first block of code in your question.

Comment: that depend of what kind of optimization you want to do :) Knowing that dynamic array don't do copy-on-write is for my side not root of evil, but on the other side, programming without knowing it IS the root of evil ;)

Comment: ahah we just both answer the same think at the same time ;)

Comment: What you shouldn't do is indiscriminately use the pointer cast to suppress ref counting. If you were ever to use that code, do so by first extracting it into a method, so that you didn't make the call sites ugly. But more important, only ever use those ref count suppressing casts if you measured a difference in performance. Which you would not because that code would never be a bottleneck.

Comment: Originaly i use the pointer cast to suppress the copy-on-write because it's was not evident that their was not copy-on-write on Tbytes when their is on ansiString (that another good question, why such a different behavior for a very similar container)

Comment: You are illustrating my point nicely here. A lack of understanding coupled with decision taking made without proper measurement of performance. This is classic premature optimisation territory. I also wonder why you keep going on about copy on write which does not apply to a swap like this, even for types that implement the COW. Change the type of variable to a string and there will still be no COW. So yes, you've learnt something, but of the three lessons to be learnt, it seems only one has sunk in. Namely that dynamic arrays don't have COW, ironically the lesson that has no impact here!

Comment: The other things to learn are that COW for strings applies when the string content is modified, and that optimisation should only be performed with concrete real world performance measurements to guide.

Comment: @loki: if you had read the Delphi language guide, i.e. if you had actually learned the language, you would have known. Learn the language and probably half of your many questions won‘t be necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was already answered your code of swapping two TBytes between each other is the most efficient.
So my post here isn't an answer to your question but instead with it I'm trying just to warn you about how you can possibly screw up performance by using this code impropriety where performance loss will be actually caused by the code that is calling this code from your question.

Now based on the fact that you are even thinking about performance of such small piece of code I'm guessing you are probably planning on executing of this code in one large loop where slightest gain in performance of this code might have big consequences on overall performance of your application. If you would have called this code a few times I bet you wouldn't worry about its performance at all since it would be negligible to the performance of your entire application.

So if you follow the David's suggestion of putting this code into a procedure I'm guessing you might write something like this:

```
procedure SwapBytes(var A,B: TBytes);
var Temp: Tbytes;
begin
  Temp := A;
  A := B;
  B := Temp;
end;
```

Nothing fancy. But the problem with this would be that every time you would call this procedure in your loop your application will have to initialize (allocate memory for it) that local variable upon entering the procedure and then finalize (release its memory) it on exiting the above procedure. Now why is this so bad? Because allocating od deallocating memory is much slower than actually writing to or reading from already allocated memory.

So how can you avoid this problem? You do so by initializing the Temp variable outside of your procedure and pass it to the procedure as additional parameter instead. Performance gain can be significant this way can be significant.

Here is my test example where I used both approaches and measure their performance.

```
//Basic procedure for swapping two TBytes values between each other
//It has local variable Temp of TBytes type which is automatically created when
//entering the procedure and released when exiting the procedure
procedure SwapBytesLocalTempVariable(var A,B: TBytes);
var Temp: TBytes;
begin
  Temp := A;
  A := B;
  B := Temp;
end;

//Same as above bit this procedure does not contain any local variable so you
//need to pas the Temp variable as an additional input parameter
procedure SwapBytesExternalTempVariable(var A,B,Temp: TBytes);
begin
  Temp := A;
  A := B;
  B := Temp;
end;

//Quick procedure for testing
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var A,B: TBytes;
    I: Integer;
    SW: TStopWatch;
    Temp: TBytes;
begin
  //Calling first procedure with local temp variable in a loop many times can be
  //quite slow because your program needs to initialize and release that local
  //variable in each loop cycle.
  SW := TStopWatch.Create;
  SW.Start;
  for I := 0 to 100000000 do
  begin
    SwapBytesLocalTempVariable(A,B);
  end;
  SW.Stop;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Swap bytes with local variable: %f',[SW.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds]));

  //Calling second procedure which does not have local temp variable and passing
  //the temp variable as additional parameter is much quicker because this way
  //the Temp variable isn't initialized and then released in each loop cycle but
  //instead we created (initialized) it outside the loop (out OnClick method of
  //TButton and is therefore being reused in each loop cycle.
  SW := TStopWatch.Create;
  SW.Start;
  for I := 0 to 100000000 do
  begin
    SwapBytesExternalTempVariable(A,B,Temp);
  end;
  SW.Stop;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Swap bytes with external variable: %f',[SW.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds]));
end;
```

Now as you can see the performance difference of these two approaches is quite significant. During my testing calling first procedure with local variable took about **1800** millisecond (almost two seconds) while calling second procedure where I pas Temp variable as additional parameter to it only took about **800** milliseconds. Now that is **one second performance gain** between the two mentioned approaches.

Any way the general advice is to try and reduce the number of memory allocations as much as possible and try to reuse variables where possible.

Comment: Yes :) This allocation / deallocation was very hurting the perf, when we speak about millions loops it's really matter !

Comment: @loki: you are swapping millions of TBytes in a loop? What for?

Comment: What happens if you use Pointer casts and a local Pointer variable? Can‘t test on this iPad.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis because i use window api writefile with FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING to do some recovery process and in this way the buffer (even in memory, not only the write pointer) need to be sector aligned :( and as i work on pretty big file (+1 TB) i need to swap the Tbytes buffer zillions times :( ... i didn't yet try to use local pointer variable, i will try to see if it's change something

Comment: If you need sector alignment, allocate a two or more sector size TBytes and use an offset **into the array** that matches a sector alignment. Should be easy to calculate. I don't know your code, but if you can avoid swapping, you could save some time. Although, if you are reading and writing 1TB from a HD, the few seconds extra (in total!) probably won't matter.

Comment: @loki Using local Pointer variable Will be causeing same slowdowns as using of TBytes variable since TBytes is a referenced type which is basically just a pointer.

Comment: @loki In the above coment you also claim that you are working with data from big files. I seriously hope you are not writing to or reading data from these files in small blocks. Why? Becouse reading or even worse writing data into files using small blocks can seriously hurt your performacne. This is caused due to limitations of the file system itself and if your data resides on the mechanical drive also due to the hardware limitation of these drives as well ...

Comment: ... So you should consider loading larger chunks of data into memory, before processing and then writing that data back to file after it has been processed. Also you might want to consider using multithreading in combination with two memory buffers so that while you are processing one block of data in one buffer you can use another thread to either load another block of data to second buffer or save already processed data from the second buffer to your file ...

Comment: @SilverWarior: Yes i know about writing ou reading in small blocks. but in my case i need to do that when hard drive is defect and it's have bad block. I detect bad block when the read is too slow! So i need to read sector by sector. Performance is slow yes, but doesn't matter it's very punctual task. about my question to swap 2 Tbytes variable it's was mostly for theory, i just want to know the most efficient way from the theory :)

Comment: .. This way you avoid waiting for file system to finish reading or writing data to or from memory

Comment: @loki If you are expiriencing slowdowns due to hardware difficulties then using multithreaded read and write as mentioned above would surely imrpove the overal peroformance becouse becouse the hardware slowdows are causing your eintire application to wait for the hardware to deliver the needed data. I used such approach years ago in one of my old application in order to increase the file encryption performance on my old AMD athlon computer where HDD was actually my bottleneck.

Comment: This test is totally bogus. If I do the same, I get 2913 and 1145 milliseconds for these two tests. But if you use *real, allocated* `TBytes` (using `SetLength`), then the results are 6512 and 6729 milliseconds respectively, i.e. the one **with the local `Temp` variable** is slightly *faster* than the one where the `Temp` variable is passed in. And I did a test with a local `Pointer`variable and `Pointer()`casts too, and that only took 589 milliseconds, i.e. it is at least 10x as fast as the other two.

Answer (score 1):

There is no copy-on-write for dynamic arrays, but if there were, it would not matter, because nothing is written (to the contents of the arrays).

Your way is the most efficient: only references are copied, and a few reference counts are updated.

The way using pointers would be slightly more efficient (no refcounting), but also a bit more risky. You can do this because in the end, the reference counts of both arrays should be the same as they were before. If nothing can access the (local) references during the swap, it should not matter.

### Update

And if you do what David recommended, i.e. put this code in a separate procedure, then it doesn't matter a lot if you use a local `Temp`variable or an external one. But the swap using `Pointer` casts is **10x** (ten times) as fast as the normal swap using `TBytes`!

*See my comment to the other answer: it doesn't matter if you use an external or a local `Temp` variable: they are almost equally fast. I measured the one with a local `Temp` variable at an average of **6512** milliseconds, the one with the external `Temp` variable at **6729** milliseconds and the one using pointers at **589** milliseconds. I did several tests in different orders to eradicate any timing errors. There are timing differences when swapping empty (`nil`) arrays, but I assume these don't matter a lot*